# Django gets updated while installing django-fcm . How to install django-fcm without updating django

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv

My `django` version is 1.8.3. And I read it supports `django-fcm`.
I tried installing `django-fcm` in my `virtual environment` using

```
pip install django-fcm
```

sadly running this command replaced my existing `django` version to 1.10 and `djangorestframework` from 3.2.2 to 3.5.2

Here is the log

```
pip install django-fcm
Requirement already satisfied: django-fcm in /home/sudheer/virtualenvs/mediaone/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Collecting djangorestframework>=3.3.2 (from django-fcm)
  Using cached djangorestframework-3.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting django>=1.9 (from django-fcm)
  Using cached Django-1.10.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz>=2015.7 (from django-fcm)
  Using cached pytz-2016.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests>=2.9.1 (from django-fcm)
  Using cached requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: djangorestframework, django, pytz, requests
  Found existing installation: djangorestframework 3.2.2
    Uninstalling djangorestframework-3.2.2:
      Successfully uninstalled djangorestframework-3.2.2
  Found existing installation: Django 1.8.3
    Uninstalling Django-1.8.3:
      Successfully uninstalled Django-1.8.3
  Found existing installation: pytz 2015.4
    Uninstalling pytz-2015.4:
      Successfully uninstalled pytz-2015.4
  Found existing installation: requests 2.7.0
    Uninstalling requests-2.7.0:
      Successfully uninstalled requests-2.7.0
Successfully installed django-1.10.4 djangorestframework-3.5.3 pytz-2016.10 requests-2.12.4
```

Is there any way to prevent this from happening.
I just want to install `django-fcm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can this available option with `pip install -h`

pip has a `--no-deps` option.

**--no-deps**  Don't install package dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, place your application's dependencies in a requirements file whereby you can list the specific versions desired. When you want to update one package, pip will be aware of the other packages you've specified and not upgrade the packages.

requirements.txt

```
django==1.8.3
djangorestframework==3.2.2
django-fcm==<some version>
```

Then install

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```